# Write a script that prompts the user for a filename and then change the permissions of the file

Tags: shell

I know I'll use **chmod -rwxr-xr--** but how do I get the filename from the user?

Comment: So this is just a "how do I prompt from the user" question, since you already know how to do the other part? In the future, try to narrow your question only on the specific operation you're having trouble with, leaving out anything that isn't actually part of the specific problem that led you to ask a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
read file_to_change && chmod 655 $file_to_change
```

The `read` command creates a local variable (in this case `$file_to_change`) and `&&` executes `chmod 655 $file_to_change` if everything is fine with read command

Comment: `IFS= read -r file_to_change && chmod 655 "$file_to_change"`, if you want to correctly handle filenames with literal backslashes, ones that contain spaces, ones that could be misinterpreted as wildcards, etc.

Comment: ...that said, note the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), insofar as it speaks both to questions that already have answers elsewhere in the knowledgebase and questions that don't identify a specific problem the user encountered while trying to reach their goal.